# How to use datepicker in yii2?

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have used normal input field in Yii 2 to take a date. I haven't used model for input field. How can I use datepicker in that input field?

My code for input field is:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label>From</label> &nbsp;<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-   control" name="frominput" />
</div>
```

And now my JS code is:

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs("
        $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
    ");
?>
```

This doesn't show datepicker. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you got javascript code responsible for showing date picker widget registered with the view?

Comment: You can use kartik datepicker http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#markup-input

Answer (score 1):

You can use yii 2 form and model

field($model, 'from_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
    //'language' => 'ru',
    //'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
]) ?>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register jquery file and jquery.ui file

```
$this->registerJsFile(
  '@web/js/jquery.ui.min.js',
  ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your script like below in your form

> use yii\web\View;

```
 <?php
    $script = <<< JS
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    JS;
    $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
 ?>
```